# Click button by using Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying use selenium VBA to download file. However, it cannot work by using `FindElementsByXPath()`. Below codes were tried, but failed:

```
driver.FindElementByLinkText(" Download all").Click
driver.FindElementsByXPath ("//span[contains(text(),'Download all')]")
driver.FindElementsByXPath("//span[@class='mat-button-wrapper']//span[contains(text(),'Download all')]").Click
driver.FindElementsByXPath("//button[@mat-raised-button='mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-primary']").Click
driver.FindElementsByXPath("//button[@class='mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-primary' and text()='Download all']").Click
```

Snapshot of the HTML:

[image]

Comment: Error messages for each attempt? Website public? Please insert html using snippet tool via [edit], not as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element <kbd>Download all</kbd> you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByCss("button.mat-focus-indicator.mat-raised-button.mat-button-base.mat-primary span.mat-button-wrapper").Click
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  driver.FindElementByXPath("//button[@class='mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-primary']//span[@class='mat-button-wrapper' and text()='Download all']").Click
  ```